# Possible to move the cursor word-by-word with Cmd+left/right instead of Alt+left/right?

Tags: macos, keyboard, ui

I would like to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to move the cursor word by word in Mac OSX (A Cocoa thing I guess).

Is it possible to change that?

And by the same token, I would like to move the cursor to the beginning and end of the line by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> instead of <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and save this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{
    "@\UF702" = moveWordBackward:;
    "@\UF703" = moveWordForward:;
    "~\UF702" = moveToBeginningOfLine:;
    "~\UF703" = moveToEndOfLine:;
    "~$\UF702" = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:;
    "~$\UF703" = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:;
}
```

You can't change ⇧⌘← or ⇧⌘→ though. And it doesn't work in some text views or Xcode or Firefox.

Using KeyRemap4MacBook, you could add this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_SHIFT | VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_SHIFT | VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_OPTION</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_OPTION</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_COMMAND | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_COMMAND | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT</autogen>
```

It would make going back with ⌘← and changing tabs with ⇧⌘← stop working though.

See the source for the [key code constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/version_8.0.0/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/).

Comment: The first option is best because it doesn't overwrite the other keybindings.  Also [this page](http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html) is a great reference for customizing your DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), I just created two new macros.

The first has a "hot key trigger" of < command >< left arrow > and does a "type a keystroke" of < option >< left arrow >

The second is the reverse, a "hot key trigger" of < option >< left arrow > and does a "type a keystroke" of < command >< left arrow >.  And it does work.

You could then add 2 more macros for the right direction.

The way I wrote them as a quick test they are system wide but they can be limited to specific sets of applications.

While [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) is not free, it does have time limited demo.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would prefer a free method. I bet there's some way to dig in the settings/files of the system somehow...

Comment: +1 This is the best option for me on macOS Sierra. I used it to remap word selection and word "hopping" to match the Windows combinations.

Comment: This works pretty much perfectly for me. Keyboard Maestro is exceptionally powerful and can be used for tons of automation.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [KeyBindingsEditor](https://web.archive.org/web/20171003175126/http://www.cocoabits.com:80/KeyBindingsEditor/) (free) to edit the `DefaultKeyBindings.dict` and it works great (even in Firefox and XCode).

[image: cursor settings with KeyBindingsEditor]

Leaving the thumb button on the ⌘ key while cruising the text cursor works so much better -- it should be the default!

Comment: I haven't tried this in Yosemite. Do you know if still works?

Comment: It does!! :) :) :)

Comment: Does not seem to work on Sierra - the app window does not show up :(

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner) to you. It's a powerful system plugin to remap keys and key combinations. You can map whatever key combos you want to whatever in your mind. Please check it out and you will fall in love with it

Comment: How exactly would Karabiner need to be configured to accomplish the task described in the question?

Comment: I like Karabiner. I guess I'd have to look at the source code to find out how it works.

Comment: just set the cmd + left as the trigger for karabiner to send the event of alt + left. And you can even restrict the remap of the keys within certain applications or windows

Answer (score -1):

word-by-word: <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>

go to start/end: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: Yes the OP knows this - they want to know how to change it.

Comment: thanks for them!!