# CMD+Left Arrow, CMD+Right Arrow -- Jump Word

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I've switched my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key to replicate my hotkeys on Windows. I've fixed my home and end keys to behave as I'd like and now all that's left is remapping my <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to behave properly.

So far - tried a bunch of things suggested on StackOverflow and really can't get it to work. I've tried:

- [Possible to move the cursor word-by-word with Cmd+left/right instead of Alt+left/right?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80960/possible-to-move-the-cursor-word-by-word-with-cmdleft-right-instead-of-altleft) (accepted answer and KeyBindingsEditor program).
- The following in my `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` (from http://heisencoder.net/2008/04/fixing-up-mac-key-bindings-for-windows.html):

  ```
  {
  "\UF729"   = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";                       /* Home         */
  "@\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:";                   /* Cmd  + Home  */
  "$\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:";     /* Shift + Home */
  "@$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Cmd  + Home */
  "\UF72B"   = "moveToEndOfLine:";                             /* End          */
  "@\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfDocument:";                         /* Cmd  + End   */
  "$\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";           /* Shift + End  */
  "@$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:";       /* Shift + Cmd  + End */
  "\UF72C"   = "pageUp:";                                      /* PageUp       */
  "\UF72D"   = "pageDown:";                                    /* PageDown     */
  "$\UF728"  = "cut:";                                         /* Shift + Del  */
  "$\UF727"  = "paste:";                                       /* Shift + Ins */
  "@\UF727"  = "copy:";                                        /* Cmd  + Ins  */
  "$\UF746"  = "paste:";                                       /* Shift + Help */
  "@\UF746"  = "copy:";                                        /* Cmd  + Help (Ins) */
  "@\UF702"  = "moveWordBackward:";                            /* Cmd  + LeftArrow */
  "@\UF703"  = "moveWordForward:";                             /* Cmd  + RightArrow */
  "@$\UF702" = "moveWordBackwardAndModifySelection:";   /* Shift + Cmd  + Leftarrow */
  "@$\UF703" = "moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:";   /* Shift + Cmd  + Rightarrow */
  }
  ```

Any ideas why this won't work for me?

Comment: So, do you want a fix, or do you want to know why your described method is not working?

Comment: @CousinCocaine A fix would be preferred.

Comment: Looked at Karabiner? https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en

Comment: Both options work for me. I even did a straight copy from your posted code. Remember for the effects to take place you must logout and back in.

Comment: @markhunte That is interesting. Can I double-check? To test it, did you switched the CTRL and CMD key as described and saved the dict to ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict , logged out and back in and now you can jump words with CMD-arrow?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I copied the exact code you have posted. And I also did the same for the code in the other answer. CMD+ arrows jumped words instead of to ends.

Comment: @markhunte Thanks for the heads-up. (I'm not the OP but just interested).  So that would mean that the error is somewhere else - assuming that the OP has logged out and back in since the file has been edited. So basically this is new and useful information for the OP.

Comment: @markhunte Yeah -- no dice for me. I've logged out and back in. I wonder if it's because I'm using a Microsoft keyboard.

Comment: That is possible, only one way to find out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you are trying to do this via KeyBindings, but here is an alternative method using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/):

[image: Keyboard Maestro to remap keys]